# Should I post a question that I'm going to immediately close as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, self-answer, dupehammer

Last week, I finally found something to ask on Stack Overflow! I kept track of my research and knocked out a bare-bones replication of the problem. I typed out the question and pasted it into the Ask Question form.

All those "Questions that may already have [my] answer" popped up, and I checked them out, too. Nope. Nope, already saw that one. Nope, saw that. Ooh, let me try that...nope. And so on.

Then I got to the end of the list (no kidding, it was the *last* item): a question I hadn't seen before, because it **didn't contain any of the keywords that I had thought of for my problem**. The setup wasn't the same at all in the broad strokes, but there was one strong connection, so I tried out the answer, while thinking that it could never work: it should be equivalent to a line of code that I already included. But, it worked!

I never found this other question because there was almost no verbal overlap despite there being a *core* equivalence. I now find myself inclined, equipped with [Mjölnir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/159251), to perform a variation on [self-answering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow) in which I post my sincere and [painstakingly-researched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/603977) question, then immediately close it as a duplicate of the question where I found the solution.* I think this would widen the search target for the problem/solution in a way that would be beneficial. You know, the whole justification for duplicate closure in the first place.

What do you think of this? **Does "answer your own question" extend to "plant your own signpost"?** Or is it an abuse of my dupehammer, swinging my rep around? Am I just too emotionally attached to my already-written question?

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027804/in-custom-modal-presentation-uitransitionview-ignores-auto-layout-constraints is the subject post.)

---

Closely related, but I haven't posted, let alone gotten an answer yet: [I want to, and do not want to, close my question as a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305673/i-want-to-and-do-not-want-to-close-my-question-as-a-duplicate)
Also: [Delete question or close own post as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284274/delete-question-or-close-own-post-as-duplicate)

Related, but I'm not re-posting about the *same* situation (also doesn't include the dupehammer angle): [Is it okay to intentionally duplicate a question if you think you can ask it better?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268665/is-it-okay-to-intentionally-duplicate-a-question-if-you-think-you-can-ask-it-bet)

Related, but in the opposite direction: [I posted a canonical Q&A to a problem I solved, but now it's marked as duplicate to an older question with an incomplete solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285439/i-posted-a-canonical-qa-to-a-problem-i-solved-but-now-its-marked-as-duplicate)

Not related because in it, the original does *not* solve the problem: [What to do when the question you want to ask is a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253924/what-to-do-when-the-question-you-want-to-ask-is-a-duplicate)

---

*The target question is a good post, too, so I'd never think of [closing it as a duplicate of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/603977).

Comment: Tangentially related: [Is it valid to vote to close as duplicate when the questions are at first glance unrelated?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262853) but I'm convinced that the answer's `YES` for this situation. The solution is completely straightforward and transparently applicable to my post.

Comment: If you ask me, post away. Not sure what the community at large thinks tho

Comment: Well, that's about where I sit, too, @Pekka웃; I'm very interested in everyone's opinions, especially if there's some downside I'm not seeing. Thanks for your "yea" vote.

Comment: FWIW one doesn't even need dupehammer to self-close that way. 15 or maybe 50 rep (to flag own question for dupe), then press ["that solved..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/165773) button

Comment: That's a strong argument that the system is in favor, @gnat; I didn't think of that.

Comment: Honestly, I see NOTHING wrong with this. If you just couldn't find the previous post because it was so unlike your own question, won't Stack benefit from a more easily searchable question?

Comment: In a sense we do want duplicates. Just another way for an end user to find the best content. It is especially useful if the question contains other keywords that might help the next person get to the right answer.

Comment: I'm upvoting this so that it might get in front of more eyes. After hearing so many people whine about their "special snowflake" questions getting closed as a dupe, the idea that someone actually wants to close their own question as a duplicate is just that refreshing.

Comment: Closing as duplicate is my second favorite feature of this platform, @MikeMcCaughan, right after universal editing. I love the idea of funneling problems down to their core solutions.

Comment: Would it be possible to edit the original question so that it included more keywords?

Comment: Not a bad thought, @AndrewMorton; there's one small thing I could edit in, but other than that I'd have to say not really, not without mangling it beyond recognition. The keywords are completely different. Analogously, the other question is about a lamp plugged into a wall outlet, while mine is about overhead track lighting. The problem in both cases turned out to be that we each thought the light switch was turned on, but it wasn't wired correctly, and it was incorrect in precisely the same way for both.

Comment: wasted effort as it will probably just age out and get deleted eventually by the system

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: if it gets upvotes it won't be deleted. If it doesn't get upvoted, I guess I don't really care: the effort I'm going to expend at this point is minimal. I already have the question typed out and ready to go; then it's just two or three more clicks to close it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson If you're talking about closed questions being automatically deleted by the Roomba, [that doesn't apply to questions closed as duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/234299). If not, what are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Based on your explanation in the comment above, it sounds a lot like the XY Problem to me: two people both misclassified or misidentified the actual cause of the problem in different ways. But sometimes, you have to go down the road to know what you didn't see at first. (Do women have an XX problem? Overtalking the actual issue?)

Comment: The XY concept doesn't really apply to troubleshooting/debugging questions, @nocomprende: it's pretty much inherent to them that you're looking in the wrong spot. XY comes up with "constructive" questions, when you're trying to build something mildly complicated and have hit on entirely the wrong tool to use, and then you ask about using that _instead of_ asking about your original problem. An XY version of my analogy would be "How do I wire this lamp cord to my wall switch so I can run power into it from the nearest outlet?" "Why do you need to do that?!" "Well, the switch has no power..."

Comment: It's s bit funny that this question is closed as dupe xD

Comment: I'm voting to delete this since its one answer is incorrect in terms of site policy, causing it to be misleading for viewers.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is a great idea. No elaboration needed; you explained why quite well already.

Comment: *Note*: While this answer is accepted and has a lot of upvotes, consensus seems to be the opposite meaning of this answer. See the answers at the [dupe target](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290768/11942268) and [this mod comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423338/should-i-create-signpost-duplicate-questions-on-purpose?noredirect=1#comment948013_423338).