# Is it acceptable to post a duplicate question if the existing question is down-voted but has a correct but unaccepted answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I fully typed out a question before spotting a potential [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29283931/1202600) in the Similar Questions list.

The existing question has been downvoted to -1 but has an unaccepted answer which, I believe, answers the existing question and my question.

Is it acceptable to post my question in hopes that it aids people looking for the same answer that might not spot the downvoted question with unaccepted answer? I could of course also refer to this existing question in mine.

For reference, my draft question reads as follows:

> **How can I share common tests across solutions?**
>
> If I have C# project containing "Tests About Tests" - used for example, to enforce that all test classes should end with "Tests" or that every class should have a corresponding test class - how can I share that project between multiple solutions so that the tests are identified and run by my test runner?
>
> Solutions I've considered:
>
> - Add the common tests as a dll/nuget reference - nunit/ncrunch doesn't appear to pick up the extra tests.
> - Use externals in svn so the project itself can be shared between solutions - I believe this would work but not sure if there's an equivalent for git
> - Add the project directly from a common location to every solution that requires it - Again this would work but is a bit brittle as it requires developers to use a particular structure when checking out solutions from source control.
>
> Is there a better way? It would be great if the first option would work as it feels like the correct one but equally the second option is feasible if git has a similar concept to svn externals (although I'm still not a huge fan of this approach!)

Comment: Related: [Should I post a question that I'm going to immediately close as a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307615/2675154)

Comment: What makes you think people would see your question and not the existing question?

Comment: @Servy: different keywords perhaps

Comment: Real question is: why was the original question downvoted? and why would your version deserve better acceptance?

Comment: Standard wisdom is that you should edit the existing question to fix whatever problems led to the downvotes. But still, you cannot accept an answer. Maybe someone can address how to deal with that issue.

Comment: Whether an answer is accepted or not really isn't that important in the grand scheme of things; what's more relevant is whether it has a reasonable number of upvotes and few or no downvotes.

Comment: @Servy: I had assumed (maybe incorrectly) that a down voted question would be treated less favourably by the search algorithm.

Comment: @thudbutt Reposting the same, or a comparable, question just because the one out there has downvotes is not an appropriate solution.  If that post has some problems, you can fix them.  If you're able to ask the same fundamental question but in a much better manor, that adds value beyond just being the same thing without downvotes, and the changes would be too extreme to be done as edits, then posting your own question could be appropriate.

Comment: @Claudiu I was asking him about this specific case.  He did not indicate in his question that he was using dramatically different wordings, or that he had addressed key problems that the old question had, merely that he had the same core question.  *If* his new question is actually making notable improvements (and my question was for him to specifically explain what he feels those improvements/differences are) then there could be some value to his question.  Without it it's just clutter.

Comment: @Josh Part: I agree, I didn't want to speculate but it looks like it ends half way through a sentence and a number of comments for more information have been ignored.

Comment: @Servy: Fair enough, having re-read both my draft and the original I don't believe it warrants a new question. If you move your comment to an answer then I think that should be the accepted answer for this question.

Comment: Note: A question does not have to have an accepted answer to be the target of a duplicate, it just needs to have an answer with a positive score.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if your question *deserves* to be closed or not - there are enough people who won't consider the nuances and will simply vote to close reflexively. You *might* get some consideration if you give a link to the other question and state why that answer doesn't work for you, but if the answer was actually adequate then why are you asking again?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It all comes down to whether or not your question is adding value over the existing question.  If you're making the question much clearer, focusing its scope, providing better examples, etc. then posting a new question can be helpful.  Ideally you'd want to just edit the existing question, but if the problems are severe enough, and you're not the original author, then that may not be an appropriate edit.  (If you *are* the author then you should almost certainly just be editing the old question.)

The only other reason to post the duplicate would be if you're asking the same core question, but in a very different way.  If you're using dramatically different vocabulary, such that someone could be searching for words you're using to try to find your problem, but where the existing question uses different terms.

If the post isn't of dramatically higher quality, nor improving the searchability of the question by adding new windows, then it's just clutter and shouldn't be posted.

Comment: Thanks Servy, as discussed in the comments above, I agree and in my case, don't feel that another question is warranted.