# Should I ask a new question in order to make the answer easier to find?

Tags: discussion

While working on a project recently, I kept running into an issue "randomly", and so I had begun to compose a question about it to post to SO. (Every time I tried searching for the answer, I couldn't find anything.) Recently, I discovered the answer to this question, so I wanted to post it on SO and self-answer so that anyone else who might have this problem could find the solution too.

As a good StackOverflowan, I searched the site some more to see if this question had been asked before. This time I found a similar question, so I was going to just answer that one instead.

However, the problem is that the only reason I found this question is that I already knew the answer. In all the searches I did before I figured out the answer, I didn't find this question. Thus, I'm concerned that future StackOverflowans that have this problem won't be able to find my answer.

In addition, I don't think the question is very clear, and it doesn't include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (In fact, the included code fails both the Minimal and Complete tests.)

I would edit the question, but that would mean modifying much of the code, which reviewers tend to look down upon. Also, I'm not *completely* sure that this question is the same issue that I had, so I don't want to turn it into something else by accident.

So these are what I see as my options:

1. Post my answer on the original question, perhaps with a note that the question should be cleaned up, and the code reduced to an MCVE.
2. Post a new question, with better keywords and an MCVE, and answer my own question. I could then mark the original question as a duplicate of mine.

What should I do?

Comment: Post a new question and self answer it (don't forget the self answer checkbox!), then immediately flag it as a dupe of the target, or, flag the other as a dupe of yours (whichever has the better answer, though be careful not to be biased!) Couldn't hurt to have a better sign post.

Comment: (Warning: The following is entirely my opinion and should be taken with a grain of salt.) If you can post an objectively better question, I don't see why you couldn't ask a new one. Especially since 1) You're not 100% sure that the other question really is the same as yours and 2) You've already got a plan for an arguably better question since you'll have an MCVE and the other, according to you, does not. Duplicates should in general leave the better question with the better answer open. Are you sure your answer will be better as well?

Comment: Why not just edit the existing question to make it more searchable / useful?

Comment: @TinyGiant Scott addresses that in the post. (Fifth paragraph.)

Comment: I guess that doesn't make sense because you don't have enough rep to unilaterally apply an edit yet, but you *could* always bring up the specific case here or in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). That way other users could collaborate on it with you.

Comment: If your question and answer are both of good quality I think @KevinB has a good approach.

Comment: Closely related: [Should I post a question that I'm going to immediately close as a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307615) You should definitely post your question.

Comment: @Kendra and Kevin: The current question has 0 answers, so I sure hope mine is better!

Comment: @TinyGiant: I wouldn't be able to fix the code sample, since it is not complete.