# Can I ask the same question in order to improve searchability?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I want to ask the question *How do I drop a MongoDB database using PyMongo?*
However, StackOverflow already contains an answer to my question but on a question with a markedly different wording than what I've been searching for.

The question is: [How to delete pymongo.Database.Database object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849999/how-to-delete-pymongo-database-database-object)

From the title of the question it's looks to be asking a different question than my own (and it kind of is), and it's not at all clear that it actually has the answer I'm looking for.

Therefore, I would like to ask my own question so that later solution-seekers will find what they're looking for faster than me.

### Backstory

I was looking for a way to drop a MongoDB database with PyMongo, and naturally I searched Google, getting the following five top results:

1. [drop a database or collection via pymongo · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/1556251) (*outdated: Only works in PyMongo < 3*)
2. [Remove Data with PyMongo — Getting Started With ...](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/python/remove/) (*doesn't contain solution*)
3. [database – Database level operations — PyMongo 3.2.1 ...](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html) (*doesn't contain solution*)
4. [python - How to delete pymongo.Database.Database object ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849999/how-to-delete-pymongo-database-database-object) (**StackOverflow link, contains solution**)
5. [How to drop a MongoDB using pymongo - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-drop-a-MongoDB-using-pymongo) (*top answer is outdated, but second answer contains solution*)

The problem here is that I never clicked the StackOverflow link as it seems to be asking a different question than the problem I'm trying to solve.

*Note: While making this question I actually found a [question asking basically the same thing I'm asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314210/should-i-ask-a-new-question-in-order-to-make-the-answer-easier-to-find) here on meta, worded differently. But I didn't find it in my immediate search, leading me to the exact problem I was having to begin with (searchability of questions).*

Comment: Looks like this meta-question will become an example of such a question ;-)

Comment: So many duplicates! (when you start really digging)