# Running out of questions to ask

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Whenever I have ***any*** coding question, *99.999%* of the time I can find the answer - or at least a derivative that leads to the answer, and I am usually very reluctant to post a question because I'm confident the answer exists somewhere out there!

At what point do we allow repeated questions? **for example** the answered question was years ago and the language may have evolved, is it then ok to re-ask the question? Or do we accept that we have mastered the *codi-verse* and use SO like an archive of [idiocies](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=idiocies)

Comment: You'll never run out of questions to answer.

Comment: Oh, man, I was so excited last fall when I thought that I had found a question to ask. Then I searched one last time before posting and found the answer! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307615/

Answer (score 7):

> and I am usually very reluctant to post a question because I'm confident the answer exists somewhere out there

Yup, I know the feeling - and isn't it great! All that information on your fingertips, rather than having to explain your problem, wait for someone to answer, vet their trustworthiness, wait for someone else to come by with a different answer, clarify what you mean, etc.

What a thing for a community to achieve, for all its faults.

There's still enough genuinely new questions coming in to keep us all entertained, though. We're not really running out of questions as there's constantly new technologies and problems popping up.

> for example the answered question was years ago and the language may have evolved, is it then ok to re-ask the question?

Sometimes - but typically the ideal scenario is that questions asked years ago are [updated whenever a new solution or version comes around.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer) My experience is this works fairly well much, if not most of the time. There are certainly cases where a new question is warranted, for example when a technology has changed *massively*.