# Improvement Proposal: Google Search Hits

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Is there some kind of indexing/cataloging mechanism in place that works with google to help existing, "high scoring" (aka legacy) posts get better rank/visibility?

From my personal experience, and the sheer number duplicates I've come across, it seems as though there is room for improvement in getting people to the "good" posts.

If it doesn't already exist, I would propose (for at least the "good" posts anyway) a user definable index to hold keywords that would meaningfully identify the subject matter of a post.

It's just a shame to spend a bit of time typing up a question just to have it closed due to duplication, especially when an honest effort was put in to search the site (even when prefixing with the "site: stackoverflow.com" string). Those same people monitoring for duplicates could be editing an index or something.

Comment: Something like tags?

Comment: The shear number of duplicates come from people not searching.  Most times I can search the error message or the title and get a dupe target.  That is not our fault but the OP's.

Comment: Tags are categories, correct. Categories are broad.

Comment: @SamusArin Some are broad.  Some are really narrow.

Comment: The problem is often due to people not knowing what to search for, coupled with people being unable to write useful question titles, thus making questions not findable.

Comment: @KevinB That's what I was thinking, for those questions in particular. I suppose they could be edited... But something just doesn't feel right about editing legacy posts.

Comment: The fix to that is to fix the poor question titles (or downvote/close/delete those posts) and then to dupe close the ones with good titles that are duplicates just using different terms. but that sill won't help askers who don't know what they're looking for. Nothing will help them aside from help from others.

Comment: @KevinB "dupe close the ones with good titles"?

Comment: Yes, for example a title that asks the same thing but in a different way, different terms. More than just a "x doesn't work" or "i haz a prob" title.

Comment: @NathanOliver We'll, isn't that what the "auto-search" feature is for when typing in a title (I always start with a title now, and check that list, it's really useful)?

Comment: @SamusArin Sure.  Not that that actually stops thousands of people from asking questions every day without searching first (using that feature or any other).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Those same people monitoring for duplicates could be editing an index or something.

It's funny you should propose that. That's actually the whole point of the duplicate closure system. It is a "crowdsourced" search for the most google-juicy writeups of a particular problem.

The key piece is one that you probably don't see very often because of your rep. When a low-rep or non-logged-in user -- and this is, as I understand it, the vast majority of visitors -- follows an inbound link to a question that's closed as a dupe, **they are automatically redirected to the master question**.*

We are creating and editing this index every time we link a question to a duplicate.

Pretty good, eh?

---

*I actually find this a little annoying, personally, but I don't see how else it could work.

Comment: I was considering that actually... Take for example a recent duplicated post of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547418/interface-syntax-explicit-prefixing-with-property-accessors?noredirect=1#comment76091842_44547418

Comment: I didn't find the other two posts from google or the local SO search referenced in the "Duplicate" section at the top before posting it... Should I have just left it and reposted my edits into a new question instead of editing the existing post (incase it would be more visible)?

Comment: I dunno. Usually you it's preferable to not edit a post dramatically to change its meaning, but since the duplicate seems to be a _partial_ answer and you didn't have any answers posted, I think you're probably okay.

Comment: No shame in asking a duplicate generally, as long as you did your homework and wrote it up well. See [Should I post a question that I'm going to immediately close as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307615/should-i-post-a-question-that-im-going-to-immediately-close-as-a-duplicate) (Itself a dupe; oh, the irony.)