# Streamline the process for authors to close their own questions as duplicates

Tags: feature-request, questions, duplicate-questions

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491038/msbuild-in-appveyor-vm-doesnt-seem-to-be-building-a-new-project-in-my-c-sharp-s) today, attempting to get help debugging a problem for which the root cause wasn't clear. A few hours of debugging later, I found the root cause, which turned out to be something already covered by another Stack Overflow question.

I wasn't sure what I should do with my original question. Should I answer it, referring to the answer I provided in the other question? Should I just outright delete it? Or should I flag my own question as a duplicate?

I searched Meta, and found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307615/should-i-post-a-question-that-im-going-to-immediately-close-as-a-duplicate) which suggested I should flag my own question as a duplicate.

After I flagged my question as a duplicate, I had to reload the page. Once I did, I got a notice telling me that the question might already have an answer, with a button that said something along the lines of "this was the answer!".

Given I have the ability to act independently to close my own question as a duplicate (by flagging it, reloading the page, and clicking the button), I propose that this should just happen immediately when I flag my own question.

Comment: Seems reasonable to have some version of the "confirm your duplicate" button/dialog when you self flag as duplicate.  I'm not sure how useful this would be in practice since if you found the duplicate yourself, it's unlikely you'd post a question in the first place.

Comment: @ryanyuyu This happened in practice the way I described it :) i.e. Discovering it's a duplicate after unearthing the root cause.

Comment: I think the only time I've run into this is when someone drop a link to another question as a comment without actually flagging/voting to close themselves.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: There should be a name for the law that dictates that the likelihood of finding a duplicate yourself increases tenfold after you've asked the question (as the asker) or answered it (as the answerer).