# If the author of a question agrees to a duplicate and casts a self-close vote, the question should be closed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I just asked a question [How to detect third party login is 2fa enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51298704/1841839). It only took about five minutes before one person voted it as a duplicate. After checking the duplicate, I agree that this is definitively the answer I was looking for.

Now my question is worded IMO better than the original, so I thought to leave it up rather than delete it as I normally would.

I also close-voted my question with the same duplicate before I was presented with the built-in notice to accept the existing close recommendation as pointed out by Rob in the comments. But nothing happened; it still needs 3 more votes to close the question.

IMO if the author of the question agrees to a close vote then the question should automatically close. There should be no need for five others to close it as duplicate where the author is one of the close voters.

Two or three would probably be best to prevent anyone just writing questions better and then duplicating their own answer.

Comment: You *should* have been presented with a banner to do just that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930 - I don't think it applies any special logic to the author actually *voting* though. Maybe it should as well.

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287763/why-does-this-question-show-as-marked-as-duplicate-by-community

Comment: @rob The banner only shows up if you refresh the page.  By the time i saw it i had already submitted my close vote and it just said that i could edit my question if i disagreed.   I actually had a hard time trying to figure out what the banner was it looked like a close duplicate banner but the question was still open.

Comment: Removed the `[feature request]` tag since this is already an feature.

Comment: @RobertLongson i like that feature.  Maybe it should also detect if a user has already voted it closed as well then close it as community.

Comment: That's a really confusing UI. More of a bug than a feature request, I think.

Comment: I added the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag back in and clarified the title because this is in fact asking for new functionality.

Comment: Essentially, this is requesting Mjolnir rights for all questions you have asked, given that someone else has already suggested a duplicate... or maybe just all Mjolnir rights regardless?

Comment: I am thinking if someone else close voted your question and you agree then you should automatically close like it does for someone with a gold tag

Comment: @TylerH No, Mjolnir gives you unilateral reopen rights, which shouldn't be given, and isn't being requested.  It also isn't asking for the ability to change the duplicate question list of a closed question, another right of a Mjolnir.  This is only asking for one of the Mjolnir rights on questions you've asked.

Comment: @Servy Yes that's... what my comment says. Maybe you didn't pickup on it but the [for all questions you have asked] was implied in the 2nd part as well, I just didn't think it needed to be repeated.

Comment: @TylerH And I'm saying your comment is wrong.  This is *not* proposing Mjolnir rights for all questions you've asked, because this is not proposing that people have the right to unilaterally reopen all duplicates on questions you've asked, or for people to have the right to edit the duplicate list on their own questions.  If I've missed where either of those were proposed in this question, please point them out to me.  As it is, it's proposing questions authors get *just one* of three powers given to Mjolnir users.

Comment: @Servy So maybe you're just not reading my *whole* comment. The first half says exactly what you are saying. Specifically **Mjolnir rights for all questions you have asked, given that someone else has already suggested a duplicate**

Comment: @TylerH No, the question *isn't* asking for that.  If that were given, you'd have the right to unilaterally reopen the question or change the duplicate list on your own question, which this is not proposing.  You're getting *only* the right to unilaterally close the question.  No more.  Again, Mjolnir rights is more than just the ability to unilaterally close a question as a duplicate.  Care to point out what aspect of your comment I wasn't reading that suggested this was proposing just one of the three different Mjolnir rights on questions you've asked, rather than all of them?

Comment: @Servy I see, you're concerned about the reopening aspect. I didn't think anyone would be concerned or bother about that since the functionality we're discussing here, the scope, is clearly about closing questions, not reopening them. So let me assuage your concerns explicitly and say I am only talking about the closing side of Mjolnir.

Comment: @TylerH No, I'm not only concerned with the reopening aspect, I'm also concerned about the ability to change the duplicate question list, again, the two permissions that an actual Mjolnir user would have that this is not requesting, which is why it's incorrect to say that this question is requesting users have Mjolnir access for their own questions, it's only requesting they have unilateral rights to close their own question as a duplicate, and no more.

Comment: @Servy I've already said that I'm talking about the closing power of Mjolnir here, it's pointless for you to bring up concerns of every other thing Mjolnir might do now or in the future.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261430/confirming-that-my-own-question-is-a-duplicate-by-voting-to-close-should-have-im and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368466/streamline-the-process-for-authors-to-close-their-own-questions-as-duplicates

Comment: +1 Yep I support this

Comment: I find it odd that you normally delete your duplicate questions. Duplicate questions can act as signposts. Of course, there's no need to keep the dupe if it's a very close match to an existing one.

Comment: @pm as stated I normally would have but mine question is worded better than the original I suspect it will get more search hits than the original.    There can be instances where the duplicate should not be deleted.

Comment: @DaImTo In most cases the duplicate should not be deleted unless it's a common dupe and the new question doesn't improve the chances of someone finding the dupe target. Duplicate questions aren't bad, it's dupe _answers_ that are the problem.